# Running a program inside a Windows Form in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net

This question has been answered for earlier Windows OS  multiple times on Stack Overflow and even has a video guide here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6GWgxEvibE

However, when I implement the code to start calc.exe inside my simple windows form Calc will start outside my form.  I created a form and added a click handler with this code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

And inside the click handler:

```
Process p = Process.Start("calc.exe");
p.WaitForInputIdle();
SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
```

If I add this code:

```
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
Process p= Process.Start("calc.exe");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
MessageBox.Show("Process exited at: " + p.ExitTime.ToLongTimeString());
```

It will Display a time roughly 1 second after I started.  So I'm guessing my process I'm starting is some intermediary, that ultimately starts Calc.exe and exits. This is obviously new behavior for windows, since this code use to work.  Anyone know of a way to get the final process that is the actual Calc.exe?

Comment: `calc.exe` on windows 10 is not an app any more but a shell to launch a modern app.

Comment: try notepad.exe instead of calc.exe

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  Using notepad worked as expected.